# Mysql data export tool

Tags: java, mysql, database, vagrant

so, say I have a SQL(Mysql) database containing 4 tables {A, B, C, D}

and I want to create a testing database which contains a subset of data from the first database (both in time and type).

so for example: 
"I want to create a new (identical in structure) database containing all of the data for user "bob" for the last two weeks."

the naive approach is to dump two weeks of data from the first database, use vagrant / chef to spin up a new empty database and import the dump data.

however, this does not work as each table has foreign keys with each other. 
so, if I have two weeks of data of "A", it might rely on a year old data from "D".

My current solution is to use the data layer of my java application load the data in to memory and then inserted it into the database. however, this is not sustainable / scalable.

so, in a roundabout way, my question is, does anyone know of any tools or tricks to migrate a "complete" set of data from one database to another considering a time period of 1 table and including all other related data from the other tables as well?

any suggestions would be fantastic :)

Comment: Removing the chef tag as this does not appear to be related to Chef

Answer (score 1):

Try your "naive approach", but `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` first, then run your backup queries, then `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Comment: interesting, but I ideally want this tool to be able to work without knowing what data is contained in each table.

Answer (score 1):

There is the way to recreate similar database with part of data, not so simple, but can be used:

1. Create new database (only schema), for example using [buckup](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-backup.html#header) or [schema comparer](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html#header) tool.
2. The next step is to copy table data. You could do it with a help of data comparer tool (look at schema comparer link). Select tables you need and check record data to synchronize.